# how to can I enable qDebug() calls within Qt4 (Nokia's) source code?

Tags: debugging, qt, qt4

I don't mean qDebug() within my code, but within nokia's source code.
Should I recompile Qt with "debug" option?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

qDebug() always outputs its message regardless of debug or release mode. Some qDebug()s in the Qt source code are guarded by #ifdef and therefore fire only in debug mode. Some modules use some other debug macros that only output something under some condition, e.g. phonon uses pDebug, which is only used when QT_NO_DEBUG is not set.

You can use your favorite grep tool to search the Qt sources for "debug" case-insensitively.

Comment: I realized that some `qDebug()` calls are protected by `bool qt_debug_component()` , which can be enabled setting the environment variable QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS to 1.

However, I have an embedded platform where this does not work with qt4.8 (but works with 4.7). I need to do some more tests.